# Whole buffer initalization leads to exception

Tags: c, exception, linker, stack, stack-memory

I have trouble to get a piece of code working , I have a code using a function with local buffer ,
when the local buffer is initialized then I got exception , but when just declared without any initialization it works fine , I can't understand why.
I also increased the stack size in the linker, but seems this is not the problem.

NB : I'm compiling with c99/c11 compile option which support the whole buffer initialization.

```
#define UDS_SRV_CFG2_MAX  20

NCS_PRI_FCT tUdsStatus UDS_RdbiManagement(u16 *puwLen, u8 *aubUdsData) {

    tUdsStatus eUdsStatus;
    u8 ubTableCfgIdx[UDS_SRV_CFG2_MAX] = { 0 }; // this leads to exception
    //...
}

NCS_PRI_FCT tUdsStatus UDS_RdbiManagement(u16 *puwLen, u8 *aubUdsData) {

    tUdsStatus eUdsStatus;
    u8 ubTableCfgIdx[UDS_SRV_CFG2_MAX]; // code works fine here
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You can't be "compiling with c99/c11 compile option". You either build in C99 mode, *or* you build in C11 mode. You can't do both, they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: What do you mean "whole buffer initialization"? In C (C89, C99, C11) there is no partial initialization. Objects are either uninitialised or completely (all working bytes) initialized.

Comment: And *where* do you get the exception? When `UDS_RdbiManagement` is called? Somewhere else? You *have* used a debugger to locate where the crash happens in *your* code?

Comment: I think you mean "initialization leads to different undefined behaviour (expected vs unexpected)"

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown will cause the problem you've described. See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks for your answers , the problem was infact stack alignment , which leads to exceptions , since the stack alignment of the platform is 4byts , 20 byte buffer pass the test but 15 bytes buffer failed with an exception because of wrong compiler alignement.
this was resolved by adding compile option for misalign stack and activate in the hardware the correct flag .

Nabil ,

embbeded / electronic system engineer.